# How do I revert the image burning done on my pendrive using Rufus?

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, burning, google-chrome-os, rufus

Recently, I burned an image of chromium OS into my 32 GB SanDisk pen drive. Now, I am unable to find my pen drive or any of its details in the file manager. I am on Windows 8.1, and wish to revert my drive to original state now that I am bored with chromium OS. Help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rufus developer here.

Ah, yes, the obnoxious Microsoft bug where Windows *appears* to declare a drive as innacessible if it has too many GPT partitions, as is the case with a Chromium OS image. This is [mentioned in the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Problematic_Images).

This has confused many a Windows users into believing that a perfectly working USB drive was dead...

The good news is that your drive should be recoverable.
The bad news is that you won't be able to recover it from Windows. Instead, you will have to repartition and reformat your drive from Linux or Mac.

Or you can report the issue to Microsoft so that they fix Windows to properly handle Chromium OS drives, since it's a **pure Windows bug**...

Comment: Hello there! A few weeks ago, I got a Linux Mint Cinnamon ISO burnt onto another USB Drive, further installed it onto my device, and reformatted the USB Drive which I thought was dead. Thanks for the help and for developing Rufus so we could enjoy a number of different Linux distributions!

Answer (score 0):

oh man... Its possible that you have overwritten parts of your pen drive. if that is the case, there is no way to completely revert it, but you can try recovery software like [Recuva (very easy)](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva/download/standard) or [PhotoRec (more complicated, not for beginners)](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).
But first you should check if the pendrive has a valid partition or drive letter. To do that just follow these steps:

1. Press Win+R
2. type in `diskmgmt.msc` followed by enter
3. Look for the pen drive in the list of drives
4. If it has a big partition with a black stripe its screwed. -> Go to the Recuva method.
5. If you can only see one or multiple blue ones: right click on the biggest
6. select `Change Drive Letter and Paths`
7. If there is no drive letter: click add and asign one to it
8. check in explorer if you can see the **right** files (it may contain other things)
9. if it does not work go to step 5 and try anoter one
10. If none worked Try the Recuva method

Comment: I think they just want to format it to use it again, not recover data. So if it shows in disk management delete any partitions and format it.

Comment: @Moab That's what I want to do...how do I do so? I am 14 and a complete newbie to things you've been discussing. If possible, please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: @IshanBhavsar see this, works the same way for 8.1>>>>https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10